# Is there a Mathematica function that can take only the minimum value of a parametric curve?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have a parametric equation that loops back over itself. It is much more complex than this, but here is an example. I would like to remove the loopy "cusp" things on top. I am wondering if there is a clean way to do this, perhaps by only taking the smallest value for any given x value? I would like to extract only the bottom "half" of the curve, so there is only one spot on the curve for every value of X.

```
a := 3;
b = 4;
xPlot[t_] := a * t - b * Sin[t];
yPlot[t_] := a - b * -Cos[t];

ParametricPlot[{{xPlot[t], yPlot[t]}}, {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: You're aware that if you restrict yourself to `a == b`, you'll get cycloids instead of trochoids, no?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 8):

The following identifies the loops and does not plot them.  First identify the crossing points.

```
Table[FindRoot[{xPlot[t1] == xPlot[t2], yPlot[t1] == yPlot[t2]}, {t1, 
    n Pi - 3/2, n Pi - 1}, {t2, n Pi + 1, n Pi + 3/2}], {n, -4, 4, 2}]
(* {{t1 -> -13.8421, t2 -> -11.2907}, {t1 -> -7.55888, t2 -> -5.00749}, 
    {t1 -> -1.2757, t2 -> 1.2757}, {t1 -> 5.00749, t2 -> 7.55888}, 
    {t1 -> 11.2907, t2 -> 13.8421}} *)
```

Then, obtain the first and last value of `t` between subsequent loops.

```
Partition[Delete[Flatten[{t1, t2} /. # & /@ %], {{1}, {-1}}], 2]
(* {{-11.2907, -7.55888}, {-5.00749, -1.2757}, {1.2757, 5.00749}, {7.55888, 11.2907}} *)
```

Finally, plot those regions and combine them.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{xPlot[t], yPlot[t]}, {t, First@#, Last@#}] & /@ %,
    PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

[image]

**Improved Addendum**

In response to a comment below, continuous functions of `t` producing the curve above can be defined by

```
offset = t2 /. 
  FindRoot[{xPlot[t1] == xPlot[t2], yPlot[t1] == yPlot[t2]}, {t1, -5/4}, {t2, 5/4}];
x2Plot[t_] := 
  Block[{n = Floor[t/(2 Pi - 2 offset)]}, xPlot[Mod[t, 2 Pi - 2 offset] + 2 n Pi + offset]]
y2Plot[t_] := 
  Block[{n = Floor[t/(2 Pi - 2 offset)]}, yPlot[Mod[t, 2 Pi - 2 offset] + 2 n Pi + offset]]
```

Then,

```
ParametricPlot[{{x2Plot[t], y2Plot[t]}}, {t, -4 Pi + 4 offset, 4 Pi - 4 offset},
  ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

again produces the desired curve.

**Second Addendum**

A function that literally returns "only the minimum value of a parametric curve" can be defined as follows.

```
y3Plot[t_] := Min[yPlot[t2 /. #] & /@ Flatten@NSolve[xPlot[t2] == xPlot[t], t2, Reals]]
```

Then

```
ParametricPlot[{{xPlot[t], y3Plot[t]}}, {t, -4 Pi + offset, 4 Pi - offset},
    ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

still again produces the desired curve.  This last approach is computationally slower but more general than the previous approaches.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for something that creates a new continuous function that can be used for other things, not just a way to avoid plotting the loops

Comment: @888  Now provided.

Answer (score 8):

```
a = 3;
b = 4;
xPlot[t_] := a*t - b*Sin[t];
yPlot[t_] := a - b*-Cos[t];
```

Using [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
soln = SortBy[
  NSolve[{Thread[{xPlot[t1], yPlot[t1]} == {xPlot[t2], yPlot[t2]}],
     Thread[-4 Pi <= {t1, t2} <= 4 Pi], t1 < t2} // Flatten, {t1, t2},
    Reals], #[[1, -1]] &]

(*  {{t1 -> -7.55888, t2 -> -5.00749}, {t1 -> -1.2757, 
  t2 -> 1.2757}, {t1 -> 5.00749, t2 -> 7.55888}}  *)

diff = (t1 /. soln // Differences)[[1]]

(*  6.28319  *)

pts = {xPlot[t1], yPlot[t1]} /. soln

(*  {{-18.8496, 4.16334}, {0., 4.16334}, {18.8496, 4.16334}}  *)

ParametricPlot[
 {{xPlot[t], yPlot[t]}}, {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Clear[t]

Show[
 ParametricPlot[
    {{xPlot[t], yPlot[t]}}, #] & /@ ({t, 
      Sequence @@ #} & /@ ({(t2 /. soln)[[1]] - diff, {t1, t2} /. 
         soln, (t1 /. soln)[[-1]] + diff} // Flatten // 
      Partition[#, 2] &)),
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a clever way of plotting the function, or does it actually create a new function without the cusps?

Comment: This just plots the desired result. If you need a defined function, use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html). If you have trouble with `Piecewise` post a question with the code that you tried.

Answer (score 4):

First we can get formulas for the pieces of the plot, but alas we can only solve for `x` in terms of `y`.  `Eliminate` gives a warning about using inverse functions, but we'll still be able to use its output.

```
Block[{a = 3, b = 4},
  Eliminate[{x == xPlot[t], y == yPlot[t]}, {t}]
  ];
sol = Solve[%, x]
ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. sol // Evaluate, {y, -1, 7}]
(*
  {{x -> -Sqrt[7 + 6 y - y^2] - 3 ArcCos[1/4 (-3 + y)]},
   {x ->  Sqrt[7 + 6 y - y^2] - 3 ArcCos[1/4 (-3 + y)]},
   {x -> -Sqrt[7 + 6 y - y^2] + 3 ArcCos[1/4 (-3 + y)]},
   {x ->  Sqrt[7 + 6 y - y^2] + 3 ArcCos[1/4 (-3 + y)]}}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So let's pick the third one and figure out the period:

```
-Sqrt[7 + 6 y - y^2] + 3 ArcCos[1/4 (-3 + y)] /. y -> -1
(*  3 π  *)
```

Now create an appropriate periodic expression from it:

```
f = InverseFunction[Evaluate[-Sqrt[7 + 6 y - y^2] + 3 ArcCos[1/4 (-3 + y)] /. y -> #] &][
      Abs@Mod[x, 6 π, -3 π]];

Plot[f, {x, -12 Pi, 12 Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here's another way to get the minimum `y` as a function of `x`, similar to @bbgodfrey's second addendum:

```
ymin[x_?NumericQ] := Min[yPlot[t] /. NSolve[x == xPlot[t], t, Reals]]
```

It's a bit slower than `f` above, but it produces the same graph.

```
Plot[ymin[x], {x, -12 Pi, 12 Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```